# Application Insight monitor and send alerts on status code 500?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm new to Azure.

What I want to do is monitor X amount of pages and if any of those return status code 500 I want to send out an email and/or SMS. Is this possible to do with Application Insight?

If so, could you link me to a good documentation,

if not, what would be a good option for what I want to achieve? Are there other softwares etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this functionality by creating alerts in **Azure Application Insights**.
**Smart Detection** in Application Insights can help you in sending the email notifications for performance issues or failure anomalies e-g errors with status 500 code. Read up on this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/proactive-failure-diagnostics